# CSS: Problem with formatting inner elements

Tags: css

I have a problem with this css in an online-shop. It is a cloud shop so I can't change the files only the CSS.

Is there a way to change the 4.799 Text to red? There must be some kind of a function to change everything but the "productOldPrice"-child. Any idea? Thanks.

```
<span class="current-price-container" title="Product-Title"> 
<span class="productOldPrice">UVP 4.900,00 EUR</span>
<br>
Nur 4.799,00 EUR</span>
```

Edit: To clarify the question. I have other current-price-containers, that I do not want to reformat if they don't include the productOldPrice.

Comment: If you want to *only* change the number but not the letters (e.g. "EUR" stays the default colour) then you need to be able to access the HTML. CSS alone cannot identify that specific part of content by itself. You would need a `<span>` element around the number alone, to then style only that one element.

Answer (score 0):

```
.current-price-container{
    color:red;
}
.productOldPrice{
    color:grey;
}
```

Comment: The OP seems to not know what CSS is. Could you maybe address what CSS actually is in one or two sentences in your answer? Like.. how to apply your code.

Comment: No that was not the question.... I added an EDIT: to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change the text color of the parent span, then you can change the parent's text color to red, then give the child span the default color.

```css
.current-price-container { color: red }
.productOldPrice { color: #000 }
```

```html
<span class="current-price-container" title="Product-Title"> 
<span class="productOldPrice">UVP 4.900,00 EUR</span>
<br>
Nur 4.799,00 EUR</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added an "EDIT:" to clarify the question. This is not working, because I only want to reformat the current-price if the oldprice-child exists.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it :)

```css
.current-price-container  {color:red}
.productOldPrice{color:black}
```

```html
<span class="current-price-container" title="Product-Title"> 
<span class="productOldPrice">UVP 4.900,00 EUR</span>
<br>
Nur 4.799,00 EUR</span>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the :not pseudo selector, which might suit your logic of "...everything but (x)".

```
.current-price-container .productOldPrice {
        color: black;
    }

.current-price-container:not(.productOldPrice) {
    color: red;
}
```